# aio_read from STDIN_FILENO returns EAGAIN in OS X

Tags: c++, c, macos, aio

When I compile this code in OS X:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <aio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int, char*[])
{
    const int iBufSize = 1<<20;
    unique_ptr<char[]> pBuffer(new char[iBufSize]);
    int iRet;

    int iOpts = fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL);
    cout << "GETFL Before: " << iOpts << endl;
    fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, iOpts & ~O_NONBLOCK);
    iOpts = fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL);
    cout << "GETFL After: " << iOpts << endl;

    aiocb cb = {0};
    cb.aio_fildes = STDIN_FILENO;
    cb.aio_buf = pBuffer.get();
    cb.aio_nbytes = iBufSize;
    iRet = aio_read(&cb);
    cout << "aio_read retuned " << iRet << endl;
    cout << "errno = " << strerror(errno) << "(" << errno << ")" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

compile it with g++, then execute it like so:

```
echo "Hello" | ./aio_read\ demo
```

it returns:

```
GETFL Before: 0
GETFL After: 0
aio_read retuned -1
errno = Resource temporarily unavailable(35)
```

Why?  If I run it without the preceding `echo "Hello" |` it works as expected.  Also, the fcntl calls aren't required to cause the problem but they do show that STDIN does not have `O_NONBLOCK` set.

Comment: What compiler options did you use? I built it and it works without error using: `g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -lrt -o "bin/fcntl" "fcntl.cpp"`

Comment: `g++ -std=c++11 fcntl.o -lrt -o fcntl` works for me (as long as you add `#include <string.h>`) in Linux and behaves as it should but in OS X Mavericks (10.9.3) I use `g++ -std=c++11 fcntl.cpp -o fcntl` and get the error.

Answer (score 1):

> *If I run it without the preceding `echo "Hello" |` it works as expected.*

Seven and a half years later, this is a problem for me, too.

Unfortunately, OS X at the time of this writing does not support aio on pipes.  Thus, your piped input fails with EAGAIN, but `aoi_read` on other stdin inputs — a terminal, `< /dev/null`, plain files — succeeds.

At least one open source project [has also run into this limitation](https://github.com/fildesh/fildesh/issues/16#issuecomment-778722718).